# jquery php live search

Tags: php, jquery, livesearch

ive got working live search with ajax and php

JQUERY:

```
$("#search").keyup(function()   {
   var search_input = $(this).val();
   var dataString = 'keyword='+ search_input;
      if(search_input.length>1){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "include/search.php?diary_date",
      data: dataString,
      beforeSend:  function() {
             $('#loading').addClass('loading');
          }, success: function(server_response) {                 
               $('#searchresultdata').html(server_response).show();
           $('span#faq_category_title').html(search_input);
    }
});
}return false;
});
```

PHP:

```
$q = "SELECT id_user, f_name, l_name, postcode, email,telp FROM user 
WHERE f_name LIKE '%$keyword%' 
OR l_name LIKE '%$keyword%'
OR email LIKE '%$keyword%'
OR postcode LIKE '%$keyword%'";
```

i want the search result, search from the first letter not from the middle or last for example:
keyword = JO
Result i want =
* JOHN BECKS
* JONATHAN WILKO
* KATY JOANS

for a moment the system pick up not only first even middle & last words
* TONY NESJO
* BAJOZ ZACKS

Comment: simple, in your queries imagine `%` as `*` so if you emit the first `%` it would search like `JO*` but in SQL its `JO%`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the first `%` from each of your `LIKE` strings.

```
$q = "SELECT id_user, f_name, l_name, postcode, email,telp FROM user 
WHERE f_name LIKE '$keyword%' 
OR l_name LIKE '$keyword%'
OR email LIKE '$keyword%'
OR postcode LIKE '$keyword%'";
```

That said, you should *really*, *really* investigate using PDO or similar and sending a bound query, where each parameter gets properly escaped to prevent SQL injection attacks.

If you do that the SQL gets slightly more complicated, though, because you can't bind a parameter inside a string, so the addition of the `%` has to be done as a SQL concatenation:

```
$q = "SELECT id_user, f_name, l_name, postcode, email,telp FROM user 
WHERE f_name LIKE CONCAT(?, '%')
OR l_name LIKE CONCAT(?, '%')
OR email LIKE CONCAT(?, '%')
OR postcode LIKE CONCAT(?, '%')";
```

(then produce a prepared statement handle and execute with the appropriate parameters - you'll find plenty of examples else where on Stackoverflow).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) operator like so:

```
$q = "SELECT id_user, f_name, l_name, postcode, email,telp FROM user 
WHERE f_name REGEXP '^$keyword' 
OR l_name REGEXP '^$keyword'
OR email REGEXP '^$keyword'
OR postcode REGEXP '^$keyword'";
```